# Is there EC2 Elastic IP that is public facing? without NAT?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sip, nat

I am hosting a SIP server in EC2 using elastic IP. However, I read that SIP server doesn't really work well if the server is not public facing (using NAT), because from what I read at AWS site, elastic IP is using 1:1 NAT.

> The Elastic IP address is mapped to the instance using 1:1 NAT. The
>   instance itself is not aware of the public address.

Is there any public facing non-NAT static IP address that I can buy from Amazon and assign to my server? Or, this action is actually useless?

Thanks!

Comment: The NAT they refer to is at the AWS level and is transparent to the public.  It is NOT the same thing as a NAT Gateway or NAT instance.  Have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have EC2 instance with public IP without NAT. Nevertheless all major PBX, proxy server or SIP server should work well with NAT. Freeswitch for example even have manual for running it in EC2:

https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Amazon+EC2

If you still want to get rid of NAT, you can try Digitalocean, it is similar to Amazon but without NAT.

Comment: If you have a public IP, you do not need a NAT Gateway or instance for the VPC/subnet.  Those are only required if you do not assign public IPs to all your instances but they still need (outgoing, not incoming) Internet acces.

Comment: @KarenB is correct.  If there is some oddity with SIP software that it doesn't work with Amazon "public" addresses that's another matter

Comment: Nobody is saying that some software is not working with Amazon, but exactly opposite, it is working and I provided even link with manual for configuring Freeswitch on AWS. Point is that SIP was not design initially to work with NAT, cause at that point when protocol was designed there was no NAT at all and because of this if you want to run VoIP software in NAT environment you will need to do some additional configurations and if somebody want to eliminate this additional configuration it is up to him.